# UK driving - Games or Simulator

Tags: uk, driving

I am an American and will be moving to the UK next month and I would like to drive around in a week's time to look for houses.

I am sub-consciously oriented to driving on the right side of the road and I was wondering if there are any games or simulators that are effective to re-wire the muscle memory for driving on the left?

I am looking especially for simulators or games because I am not fully sold on the idea of "learn-as-you-make-mistakes" idea yet.

Comment: How many years of driving experience do you have? It's probably not as difficult as you think (speaking from personal experience).

Comment: You should reword the question to ask specifically about driving games, otherwise your specific question has already been asked as Michael has pointed out.

Comment: I learnt to drive in the USA and then drove there for many years before moving to the UK.  In the UK, I hired a car for a weekend and drove slowly around the side street near the place where I stayed.  It took me about an hour or so to readjust to driving on the left.

Comment: Thanks, Greg and Aleks! I have visited UK a couple of times and I felt very disoriented even when I was in the passenger seat :) Knowing myself, I am not a quick study either. I would like to build my confidence somewhat before even test driving with a rental car. Hence, the request for a simulator.

Comment: A better option would be to pay a driving instructor for some lessons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are a few games. Do I think it would help? I don't honestly think it's such a big deal that you need a simulator. I would be more inclined to practice in a controlled few blocks of low traffic and drive around in that area until I feel more comfortable. Just like driving in the United States/Canada, you can easily be overwhelmed by driving variables you're not used to. Thus, I would recommend starting out with few variables in the UK and progress as you feel comfortable. I would also familiarize myself with the common road signs and traffic laws which may be different.

Start here: UK Driving Safety info
https://www.gov.uk/browse/driving/highway-code-road-safety
This seems more important to me than trying to change your subconscious left-right hand driving habits.

Regarding games:

There is Euro Truck Simulator which involves left hand driving:
http://www.eurotrucksimulator.com/

Then there's this company which has a UK version of their simulator:
http://citycardriving.com/

And there's SimuRide which makes a less expensive home edition:
http://www.simuride.com/

I'm not personally reviewing any of these games for quality / helpfulness. Whether they are effectively going to help is going to depend on the person. These are the only UK based driving games or simulators I'm aware of.

GTA 3 also had a London 1969 mod. I don't know if it changed the driving of traffic from right to left though. Or, if you sat on the other side of the vehicle. But, it might be another game to research as GTA is very sand-box and has a lot of other traffic and working lights etc. should you chose to obey them or break the law a lot as the game more or less entices you to.

Comment: Thanks, maplemale. This information is very helpful. I also found this not-so-fancy 2D simulator online: https://framesynthesis.com/drivingsimulator/2d/

Comment: Another good one would be practice tests for the UK "Hazard perception test" (there are many online,  and many apps, [here's one example](http://www.2pass.co.uk/mockhazardtest.htm#.WE-047KLQ5Y)). They're basically video clips of real UK driving where you have to click the screen when you spot things a driver would need to react to, and you score points based on your reactions. It's a good way to train yourself to look in the right (opposite) places for possible hazards, and get familiar with other differences of UK roads (e.g. narrower than US roads, more pedestrians, more cyclists, etc)